# What does volume mean on a weekly chart

Tags: market-data

For a weekly chart, I know that:

1. open price means the opening price on Monday
2. previous price means the previous price on Monday
3. last price means the last price on Friday
4. high price means the highest price during the week
5. lowest price means the lowest price during the week

What does volume mean?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a chart you are looking at.  I think it varies between total volume and average volume.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some more context?  I guess you are talking about a chart for an investment, but beyond that, it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weekly volume is usually the sum of the daily volumes for that week.

Answer (score 1):

Probably average daily volume for that week.